# Is there any way to override or hide the standard "Import" list view button in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, import, action, button-overrides

In Lightning, the **Recently Viewed** list view for a custom object has **New** and **Import** buttons by default:

[image: Default list view buttons]

I would like to override or hide the **Import** button since our custom object has a custom import process.

The override works fine for the **New** button as explained here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=assign_action_overrides.htm&type=5

But the same process doesn't work for the Import button due to the following:

- **Import** does not appear in the list of actions
  I was able to get around that by hacking the Setup URL (edit the New action and replace **New** by **Import** in the URL)
- The editor only shows the Classic override option
  Not the Lightning and Mobile ones available for the **New** action
  [image]
- But most importantly, the Classic override does not work
  Nothing happens when I click the modified **Import** button. 
  So at least it disables the default behavior -- which is something I guess -- but I would really like to attach my own. Even when I select the exact same Visualforce page that I use successfully for the **New** button nothing happens when it **Import** is clicked. Nothing in the log either

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Import Button can be disabled from Lightning Page layout.
You can achieve this by **revoking permission for particular user on concerned object**.

Comment: Thanks @Adamo but I don't think there is a specific permission for Import. You can most likely remove the button by removing Create permission -- but I actually want users to be able to create new records -- just not through the standard Import wizard

Answer (score 0):

There is an import permission:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000352015&type=1